# Is there any difference between a "derivative" and a "directional derivative"?

Tags: derivatives, differential

See [What is directional derivative?](https://qr.ae/TUn74K)

> It is just the usual derivative i.e. the ONE VARIABLE/ONE DIMENSIONAL
> Derivative obtained from breaking down a VECTOR DERIVATIVE.
>
> This example will make it clear. Consider a humming bird moving around
> you. You are interested(assume!) in the change in the position of the
> bird with respect to time(i.e. its velocity). But being a
> mathematician(assume!), you realize that NOT 1, but actually 3 -
> Variables: x, y and z are changing. So you call the Velocity in
> X-direction as the DIRECTIONAL DERIVATIVE OF THE POSITION WITH RESPECT
> TO TIME IN THE X DIRECTION…
>
> I hope you understand. If not, ponder for a few days. Even if you
> don’t understand then, just let me know.

See [How different is directional derivative from the usual derivative f'?](https://qr.ae/TUn7Pc).

> **All** derivatives are directional derivatives, sort of. The directional derivative indicates the rate of change of the function in
> a specific direction. The usual derivative $f'$ of a function $f$ of
> one variable indicates the rate of change of the function in the
> positive coordinate direction. The only other direction that you can
> define for a function of one variable is the negative coordinate
> direction, and that turns out to be just $-f'$.
>
> For a function of two
> variables, you have a lot more choices. There is an infinite number of
> directional derivatives, one for each direction in the plane.
> Fortunately, you don’t have to calculate them all separately, it’s
> enough to compute the directional derivatives in two coordinate
> directions, the partial derivatives. It is particularly convenient if
> these direction are chosen to be orthogonal. Then you can obtain the
> directional derivative in any direction, given by a vector $d$, by
> forming the dot product between the  partial derivatives and the
> components of the vector $d$ expressed in the same coordinate system.

What I understand is they are the same.

So, Is there any difference between a "derivative" and a "directional derivative"?

Comment: See [Directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) : "the directional derivative of a multivariate differentiable function along a given vector v at a given point x intuitively represents the instantaneous rate of change of the function, moving through x with a velocity specified by v. It therefore generalizes the notion of a partial derivative."

Comment: So, the relation is that between a more general concept and a specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. And a big one. Let us assume that $f$ is a differentiable map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb R$.

The **directional derivative** of $f$ at a point $p$ with repect to a vector $v$ is a *number*. That number tells us how fast $f$ grows near $p$ in the direction given by $v$.

The **derivative** $f'$ at a point $p$ is a *linear map* from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb R$. And, given a vector $v$, $f'(p)(v)$ is precisely the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ with respect to the direction provided by $v$.

Comment: So, what is the difference between a partial derivative and a directional derivative then?

Comment: No big difference: partial derivatives are directional derivatives with respect to the vectors of the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function $f=f(x_1,...,x_n)$ which depends on $n$ variables the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ is a directional derivative in the direction of the vector $e_i=(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)$ wich has zeros in each entry but the i-th entry where it is $1$.

The directional derivative in a direction $h\in \Bbb R^n$ is defined like this: $$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial h}=\lim\limits_{t\xrightarrow[]{}0}\frac{f(x+ht)-f(x)}{t}$$ and is noted $D_hf(x)$. And this definition agrees with the partial derivative with respect to $x_i$ a.k.a. the directional derivative in the direction of $e_i$

[image: Wikipedia image]

Comment: text doesn't match with the plot.

Answer (score 0):

From the way in which this paragraph is worded it makes most sense to think of a function in more than two dimensions, e.g.
$$z=f(x,y)$$
in this context we know that we can take derivatives in two different dimensions, to give:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
when the term derivative is used, we usually mean the of the function with respect to its single variable $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ or we state in which dimension we intend to find the derivative "the rate of change of $z$ with respect to $x$". From this it is clear to see that we presume the positive direction in any axis ($+x$ as supposed to $-x$). All this concept of "directional derivative" introduces is that we can define a derivative in any direction compared to the function